# R median function from scratch

Tags: r, median

I am a R beginner and I tried to make a median function from scratch.

Here is my code:

```
mymedian <- function(x) {
  len <- length(x)
  sorted <- sort(x)
  if (len %% 2 == 0) {
    med1 <- sorted[len / 2]
    med2 <- sorted[(len + 1) %/% 2]
    result <- sorted[med1 + med2 / 2]
    return(result)
  } else {
    result <- sorted[(len + 1)/2]
    return(result)
  }
}
```

Im getting "NA" output. I couldn't find where the problem is.

Comment: You subset too early, try `med1 <- len/2` in line 5 and 6. And brackets might be missing in line 8.

Comment: Take a closer look, compare lines 7 and 10.

Comment: @jay.sf even with your edited code I still get "NA". I tried to merge the 2 vectors with append function can it be the problem?

Comment: I just pulled your code apart a bit with spaces, no real edits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Main issue is you're trying to index your `sorted` vector with a non-integer (e.g., 168.5). Compare your function to this:

```
mymedian <- function(x){
  len <- length(x)
  sorted <-sort(x)
  if(len%%2==0){
    i <- len/2
    med1<-sorted[i]
    med2 <- sorted[i+1]
    result <- sum(med1,med2)/2
    return(result)
  }else{
    result<-sorted[(len+1)/2]
    return(result)
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you!It solved my problem and I understood why it didnt work.

Comment: You may want to read: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/334823/6574038)

Comment: @jay.sf If I did a mistake Im sincerely sorry, I will definetely take a look at the guide and then ask my questions next time.

Comment: @jay.sf Thanks! Good to know the community stance.

Comment: @Umutcan I actually meant Brian ;)